# Design issue with a function that takes type parameters

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics, inheritance

The code below is written in Vb.Net but I'll accept a C# answer too.

---

I have a type like this below:

```
Public Class MruItem(Of T)
     Property1
End Class
```

Also, I have this one:

```
Public Class MruFileItem : Inherits MruItem(Of FileInfo)
    BaseProperty1
    Additional Properties
End Class
```

Now, I need to design a function that can take as parameter a `MruItem`, i could pass as argument for example a `MruFileItem`, or a `MruItem(of Whatever)`, then return the same type.

However, I tried it but I found the need to specify two type parameters instead one

```
Function Test(Of A, B As MruItem(Of A))() As MruItem(Of A)()
End Function
```

So, I need to call the function in this way:

```
Dim Value As MruFileItem() = Test(Of FileInfo, MruFileItem())
```

...But I would like to be able to call it in this other way:

```
Dim Value As MruFileItem() = Test(Of MruFileItem())
```

And also:

```
Dim Value As MruItem(Of Whatever) = Test(Of MruItem(Of Whatever))
```

---

How I need to adapt the function parameters or the class design to avoid passing two type parameters instead one?.

I also tried adding a narrowing `Ctype` operators from `MruItem(Of Object)` <> `MruItem(Of T)` then adapting the type parameters, with no success.

Comment: Is the function (Test) really a basic function somewhere or is it a method on one of the classes?

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for comment. It is a shared/static function declared outside of those classes, the function has the purpose to take and deserialize a collection of one of those classes.

Comment: Since a `MruFileItem` *is* a `MruItem(of Whatever)`, I am confused what the problem is (or why a serializer method - which is a very Type-specific process - would need to know about 2 Types).

Comment: That is in essence part of the same problem, because if I try to declare a function that takes a **MruItem(of T)**, I cannot declare another one that takes as parameter a **MruFileItem** (because it inherits from **MruItem(of T)**), at least I can't in the way I tried to do.

Comment: If you have/want 2 different methods to do essentially the same thing but return 2 different Types, just make them class methods.